# Get list of columns (and tables) in query from XML/JSON explain plan

Tags: xml, json, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-9.0

I have approx. 200 sql statements and I need to analyze what columns and tables are used in those columns. I've found there is XML explain plan available in PostgreSQL 9.0+.

Is there a known way how I can get list of used colums and tables from that plan?

Updated version:

**Test data**

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp.a (id integer, b integer, c integer, d integer, e integer, f integer, g integer, h integer, i integer);
CREATE TABLE tmp.b (id integer, b integer, c integer, d integer, e integer, f integer, g integer, h integer, i integer);
CREATE TABLE tmp.c (id integer, b integer, c integer, d integer, e integer, f integer, g integer, h integer, i integer);
CREATE TABLE tmp.d (id integer, b integer, c integer, d integer, e integer, f integer, g integer, h integer, i integer);
CREATE TABLE tmp.e (id integer, b integer, c integer, d integer, e integer, f integer, g integer, h integer, i integer);

insert into tmp.a values (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.a values (2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.a values (3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.a values (4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.b values (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.b values (2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.b values (3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.b values (4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.c values (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.c values (2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.c values (3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.c values (4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.d values (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.d values (2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.d values (3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.e values (2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.e values (3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into tmp.e values (4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

**Sample SQL and explain plan**

```sql
explain (verbose true, format xml, costs false)
select 
    a.b,
    a.c,
    b.c,
    d.b,
    e.f
from
    tmp.a a
    join tmp.b b using (id)
    join tmp.c c using (id)
    left join tmp.d d on (a.id = d.id)
    left join tmp.e e on (b.id = e.id)
where
    c.d = 1 and (d.f > 0 or e.g is null)
```

**XML results stored in table**

```sql
create table tmp.file (fcontent text);

insert into tmp.file values ('
    <explain xmlns="http://www.postgresql.org/2009/explain">
      <Query>
        <Plan>
          <Node-Type>Merge Join</Node-Type>
          <Join-Type>Left</Join-Type>
          <Output>
            <Item>a.b</Item>
            <Item>a.c</Item>
            <Item>b.c</Item>
            <Item>d.b</Item>
            <Item>e.f</Item>
          </Output>
          <Merge-Cond>(b.id = e.id)</Merge-Cond>
          <Filter>((d.f &gt; 0) OR (e.g IS NULL))</Filter>
          <Plans>
            <Plan>
              <Node-Type>Merge Join</Node-Type>
              <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
              <Join-Type>Left</Join-Type>
              <Output>
                <Item>a.b</Item>
                <Item>a.c</Item>
                <Item>b.c</Item>
                <Item>b.id</Item>
                <Item>d.b</Item>
                <Item>d.f</Item>
              </Output>
              <Merge-Cond>(a.id = d.id)</Merge-Cond>
              <Plans>
                <Plan>
                  <Node-Type>Sort</Node-Type>
                  <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                  <Output>
                    <Item>a.b</Item>
                    <Item>a.c</Item>
                    <Item>a.id</Item>
                    <Item>b.c</Item>
                    <Item>b.id</Item>
                  </Output>
                  <Sort-Key>
                    <Item>a.id</Item>
                  </Sort-Key>
                  <Plans>
                    <Plan>
                      <Node-Type>Hash Join</Node-Type>
                      <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                      <Join-Type>Inner</Join-Type>
                      <Output>
                        <Item>a.b</Item>
                        <Item>a.c</Item>
                        <Item>a.id</Item>
                        <Item>b.c</Item>
                        <Item>b.id</Item>
                      </Output>
                      <Hash-Cond>(b.id = a.id)</Hash-Cond>
                      <Plans>
                        <Plan>
                          <Node-Type>Seq Scan</Node-Type>
                          <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                          <Relation-Name>b</Relation-Name>
                          <Schema>tmp</Schema>
                          <Alias>b</Alias>
                          <Output>
                            <Item>b.id</Item>
                            <Item>b.b</Item>
                            <Item>b.c</Item>
                            <Item>b.d</Item>
                            <Item>b.e</Item>
                            <Item>b.f</Item>
                            <Item>b.g</Item>
                            <Item>b.h</Item>
                            <Item>b.i</Item>
                          </Output>
                        </Plan>
                        <Plan>
                          <Node-Type>Hash</Node-Type>
                          <Parent-Relationship>Inner</Parent-Relationship>
                          <Output>
                            <Item>a.b</Item>
                            <Item>a.c</Item>
                            <Item>a.id</Item>
                            <Item>c.id</Item>
                          </Output>
                          <Plans>
                            <Plan>
                              <Node-Type>Hash Join</Node-Type>
                              <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                              <Join-Type>Inner</Join-Type>
                              <Output>
                                <Item>a.b</Item>
                                <Item>a.c</Item>
                                <Item>a.id</Item>
                                <Item>c.id</Item>
                              </Output>
                              <Hash-Cond>(a.id = c.id)</Hash-Cond>
                              <Plans>
                                <Plan>
                                  <Node-Type>Seq Scan</Node-Type>
                                  <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                                  <Relation-Name>a</Relation-Name>
                                  <Schema>tmp</Schema>
                                  <Alias>a</Alias>
                                  <Output>
                                    <Item>a.id</Item>
                                    <Item>a.b</Item>
                                    <Item>a.c</Item>
                                    <Item>a.d</Item>
                                    <Item>a.e</Item>
                                    <Item>a.f</Item>
                                    <Item>a.g</Item>
                                    <Item>a.h</Item>
                                    <Item>a.i</Item>
                                  </Output>
                                </Plan>
                                <Plan>
                                  <Node-Type>Hash</Node-Type>
                                  <Parent-Relationship>Inner</Parent-Relationship>
                                  <Output>
                                    <Item>c.id</Item>
                                  </Output>
                                  <Plans>
                                    <Plan>
                                      <Node-Type>Seq Scan</Node-Type>
                                      <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                                      <Relation-Name>c</Relation-Name>
                                      <Schema>tmp</Schema>
                                      <Alias>c</Alias>
                                      <Output>
                                        <Item>c.id</Item>
                                      </Output>
                                      <Filter>(c.d = 1)</Filter>
                                    </Plan>
                                  </Plans>
                                </Plan>
                              </Plans>
                            </Plan>
                          </Plans>
                        </Plan>
                      </Plans>
                    </Plan>
                  </Plans>
                </Plan>
                <Plan>
                  <Node-Type>Sort</Node-Type>
                  <Parent-Relationship>Inner</Parent-Relationship>
                  <Output>
                    <Item>d.b</Item>
                    <Item>d.id</Item>
                    <Item>d.f</Item>
                  </Output>
                  <Sort-Key>
                    <Item>d.id</Item>
                  </Sort-Key>
                  <Plans>
                    <Plan>
                      <Node-Type>Seq Scan</Node-Type>
                      <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                      <Relation-Name>d</Relation-Name>
                      <Schema>tmp</Schema>
                      <Alias>d</Alias>
                      <Output>
                        <Item>d.b</Item>
                        <Item>d.id</Item>
                        <Item>d.f</Item>
                      </Output>
                    </Plan>
                  </Plans>
                </Plan>
              </Plans>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <Node-Type>Sort</Node-Type>
              <Parent-Relationship>Inner</Parent-Relationship>
              <Output>
                <Item>e.f</Item>
                <Item>e.id</Item>
                <Item>e.g</Item>
              </Output>
              <Sort-Key>
                <Item>e.id</Item>
              </Sort-Key>
              <Plans>
                <Plan>
                  <Node-Type>Seq Scan</Node-Type>
                  <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
                  <Relation-Name>e</Relation-Name>
                  <Schema>tmp</Schema>
                  <Alias>e</Alias>
                  <Output>
                    <Item>e.f</Item>
                    <Item>e.id</Item>
                    <Item>e.g</Item>
                  </Output>
                </Plan>
              </Plans>
            </Plan>
          </Plans>
        </Plan>
      </Query>
    </explain>
    ');
```

**Items in explain plan**

```sql
with elements as (
    SELECT trim(a[rn]) AS elem, rn
    FROM   (
        SELECT *, generate_series(1, array_upper(a, 1)) AS rn
        FROM  (
        SELECT string_to_array(fcontent, chr(10)) AS a
        FROM   tmp.file
        ) x
        ) y
    )
select 
    regexp_replace(elem, E'<Item>|</Item>', '', 'g' ) as sql_line
from 
    elements where elem like '<Item>%' 
group by 
    regexp_replace(elem, E'<Item>|</Item>', '', 'g' )
order by
    regexp_replace(elem, E'<Item>|</Item>', '', 'g' )
```

There are 25 columns in `Item` tag. However, to perform this query you need only 13: `a.b, a.c, b.c, d.b, e.f, a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id, e.id, c.d, d.f, e.g`. Is ther a way how I can get only these columns out of explain plan?

---

**Original version**

For example I do have the following query (more for illustration, no need to understand it):

```sql
select
    dd.id_databox_data,
    dd.recipient_id,
    dd.sender_id,
    lp.business_name,
    fa.repayment_identification,
    perform_time,
    dd.subject as dd_subject,
    ca.subject as ca_subject,
    d.unique_name,
    s.name,
    s.long_name,
    lld.legal_template,
    lld.issue_date,
    ca.perform_time,
    dd.id_recipient_document_ident,
    dd.id_sender_document_ident,
    dci1.ref_number,    
    dci2.ref_number     
from 
    databox_data as dd 
    join databox_data_attachments as dda on (dd.id_databox_data = dda.id_databox_data)
    join databox_attachment as da on (da.id_databox_attachment = dda.id_databox_attachment)
    join document as d on (d.id_document = da.id_document)
    join external_file_letter_data as fld on (fld.id_document = d.id_document)
    join letter_data as ld on (ld.id_letter_data = fld.id_letter_data)
    join legal_letter_data lld on (ld.id_letter_data = lld.id_letter_data)
    join legal_instrument li using (id_legal_instrument)
    left join execution e using (id_legal_instrument)
    join v_communication_act as ca on (ca.id_letter_data = ld.id_letter_data)
    join solver s using (id_solver)
    join responsibility as r on (r.id_responsibility = ca.id_related_responsibility)
    join party pr on (r.id_responsible = pr.id_party)
    join financial_accountability fa using (id_accountability)
    join flight f using (id_flight)
    join portfolio p using (id_portfolio)
    join legal_person lp on (pr.id_source = lp.id_party)
    left join v_authority va on (dd.recipient_id = va.data_box_id) 
    left join databox_document_ident dci1 on (dd.id_recipient_document_ident = dci1.id_databox_document_ident)
    left join databox_document_ident dci2 on (dd.id_recipient_document_ident = dci2.id_databox_document_ident)      
where
    ca.perform_time > (Now()::date - 1)
    and s.id_solver = 41
```

I'm using `explain (verbose true, format xml, costs false)`.

This results in the following explain plan (XML version), unfortunately I'm not able to insert the whole explain plan (SO limitation on post length), please use this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ptNcb9Jg) if you need the full explain plan version:

```xml
<explain xmlns="http://www.postgresql.org/2009/explain">
  <Query>
    <Plan>
      <Node-Type>Nested Loop</Node-Type>
      <Join-Type>Left</Join-Type>
      <Output>
        <Item>dd.id_databox_data</Item>
        <Item>dd.recipient_id</Item>
        <Item>dd.sender_id</Item>
        <Item>lp.business_name</Item>
        <Item>fa.repayment_identification</Item>
        <Item>act.perform_time</Item>
        <Item>dd.subject</Item>
        <Item>communication_act.subject</Item>
        <Item>d.unique_name</Item>
        <Item>s.name</Item>
        <Item>s.long_name</Item>
        <Item>lld.legal_template</Item>
        <Item>lld.issue_date</Item>
        <Item>act.perform_time</Item>
        <Item>dd.id_recipient_document_ident</Item>
        <Item>dd.id_sender_document_ident</Item>
        <Item>dci1.ref_number</Item>
        <Item>dci2.ref_number</Item>
      </Output>
      <Plans>
        <Plan>
          <Node-Type>Nested Loop</Node-Type>
          <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
          <Join-Type>Left</Join-Type>
          <Output>
            <Item>dd.id_databox_data</Item>
            <Item>dd.recipient_id</Item>
            <Item>dd.sender_id</Item>
            <Item>dd.subject</Item>
            <Item>dd.id_recipient_document_ident</Item>
            <Item>dd.id_sender_document_ident</Item>
            <Item>d.unique_name</Item>
            <Item>lld.legal_template</Item>
            <Item>lld.issue_date</Item>
            <Item>communication_act.subject</Item>
            <Item>act.perform_time</Item>
            <Item>s.name</Item>
            <Item>s.long_name</Item>
            <Item>fa.repayment_identification</Item>
            <Item>lp.business_name</Item>
            <Item>dci1.ref_number</Item>
          </Output>
          <Plans>
            <Plan>
              <Node-Type>Nested Loop</Node-Type>
              <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
              <Join-Type>Inner</Join-Type>
              <Output>
                <Item>dd.id_databox_data</Item>
                <Item>dd.recipient_id</Item>
                <Item>dd.sender_id</Item>
                <Item>dd.subject</Item>
                <Item>dd.id_recipient_document_ident</Item>
                <Item>dd.id_sender_document_ident</Item>
                <Item>d.unique_name</Item>
                <Item>lld.legal_template</Item>
                <Item>lld.issue_date</Item>
                <Item>communication_act.subject</Item>
                <Item>act.perform_time</Item>
                <Item>s.name</Item>
                <Item>s.long_name</Item>
                <Item>fa.repayment_identification</Item>
```

Is there a way (preferably SQL way) how can I get list of used columns and tables from such plan? It is not enough just query `<Item>` rows, because when the table appears first time in the explain plan (at the lowest level), then all columns are listed in `<Item>` tag although many of them are not needed to complete the query.

I have used the following SQL to list unique `<Item>` tags:

```sql
with elements as (
    SELECT trim(a[rn]) AS elem, rn
    FROM   (
        SELECT *, generate_series(1, array_upper(a, 1)) AS rn
        FROM  (
        SELECT string_to_array(fcontent, chr(10)) AS a
        FROM   tmp.file
        ) x
        ) y
    )
select 
    regexp_replace(elem, E'<Item>|</Item>', '', 'g' ) as sql_line
from 
    elements where elem like '<Item>%' 
group by 
    regexp_replace(elem, E'<Item>|</Item>', '', 'g' )
order by
    regexp_replace(elem, E'<Item>|</Item>', '', 'g' )
```

Comment: I don't understand the question at all.  What exactly are you trying to do here?  Do you need to pull this info from inside PostgreSQL?  Also what do you mean columns?  Are you looking at parsing all filters?

Comment: We need to document dependencies between SQL statements (queries used in our reporting system) and underlying database. By columns I mean physical columns in tables in postgresql database. Explain plan for query returns often some sort of superset of columns needed to perform the query (means the query will work even some columns displayed in explain are deleted from the database).

Comment: Ok, so are you looking at output columns?  Filter columns?  Something else?

Comment: I'm interested in all output columns, filter columns and join columns. `select coalesce(a,b) from g join c using (d) where e <> f` results in columns `a, b, d, e, f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to parse three areas of the XML.

The columns returned from the query are going to be under the first `output` element (in the `item` tags).

Each subnode of the join will have an `output` consisting of the columns the planner thinks are necessary to use.  Join columns will be here.  If this is giving you a superset, you may need to parse the contents of `join-filter` to get the information here.

These two will not give you everything you need.  You will certainly need to parse `filter` elements to pull columns out of that.

If you are going to do this in SQL you should look at the the [xml functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-xml.html) in PostgreSQL.  You can run xpath queries on xml in PostgreSQL, or run through xslt.  This will be far better than trying to parse it out with regular expressions.

The complexity of this is a bit beyond a working example, unfortunately, but I would hope this would be enough to get you started.